# Can element's height be changed, providing it is inside a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the following snippet I want the red area to have the same height as the yellow one:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  /* The above is shorthand for:
  flex-grow: 0,
  flex-shrink: 1,
  flex-basis: auto
  */
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <div style="height:100%; width:90%; background-color:red;">
      Should fill the remaining space
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row footer">
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It has `style="height:100%` however it acts like it has `height:auto`, presumably because of the flexbox. Can I adjust its height somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have flex-basis on content as 100%

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}
.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  /* The above is shorthand for:
  flex-grow: 0,
  flex-shrink: 1,
  flex-basis: auto
  */
}
.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <div style="height:100%; width:90%; background-color:red;">
      Should fill the remaining space
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row footer">
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Set `display:flex` on the .row.content div to make it into a flex container

Since the default value of `align-items` is `stretch` - the items will take up full height.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  /* The above is shorthand for:
  flex-grow: 0,
  flex-shrink: 1,
  flex-basis: auto
  */
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color:yellow;
  display: flex; /* <----- added */
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <div style="width:90%; background-color:red;">
      Should fill the remaining space
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row footer">
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the child element to use `position: absolute` (and use `position: relative` on the parent).

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  /* The above is shorthand for:
  flex-grow: 0,
  flex-shrink: 1,
  flex-basis: auto
  */
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color:yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.box .row.content div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  background-color:red;
  position: absolute;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <div>
      Should fill the remaining space
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row footer">
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```